# Append Scripts to Footer Inside An Included Pug / Jade js Chunk

Tags: javascript, pug

I am trying to figure out a way to have each included pug file house all the required scripts for that section.

Here is my initial layout template (layout.pug):

```
html
  head
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    title Hey Stack Overflow
  body
    block content

    block scripts
      script(src='/public/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')
      script(src='/public/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Let's say I have a sub template as follows (dashboard.pug):

```
extends ../layout.pug

block append header_scripts
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/public/css/bootstrap/card.css')

block content

  .project-header.col-md-12.center-text
    h2.project-title= Hello Again

  include ./locations

block append scripts
  script(src='/other_scripts.js')
```

Now what I want, is to figure out how I can get ./locations.pug to include the scripts it needs. (locations.pug)

```
section#location-list-section.locations

  p Welcome to the locations section

  block append scripts
    script(src='/yet-another-script')
```

I thought if I append the script here, then it will appear in the footer. It does! but it also appears in the script section so the script is called twice which is causing problems.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'it also appears in the script section so the script is called twice'?

Comment: The <script src='/yet-another-script')></script> appears below the <p> Welcome to the locations section </p> 

but also also bellow the other scripts:
<script src='/public/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'>
<script src='/public/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js'>